# Recursion for generating subsets of a list

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

I would like to know for this function, **why does after it runs and returns [[],[1]] which is the last line of the function? Then it would run the line smaller = genSubset(L[:-1]) again and again.** I visualized the code from pythontutor. However, i do not understand why it works this way. Someone please enlighten me. Thank You.

This function generates all the possible subsets of a given list, so, for example, input list is [1,2,3]. It would return [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]].

```
def genSubsets(L):
    res = []
    if len(L) == 0:
        return [[]] #list of empty list
    smaller = genSubsets(L[:-1]) # all subsets without last element
    extra = L[-1:] # create a list of just last element
    new = []
    for small in smaller:
        new.append(small+extra)  # for all smaller solutions, add one with last element
    return smaller+new  # combine those with last element and those without

print(genSubsets([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: In which case it runs again and again

Answer (score 1):

This function is **recursive**, that means - it calls itself. when it finishes one recursion iteration - it returns to where it stopped. This is exactly at the line `smaller = getSubsets(L[:-1])` but notice that **it wont run it again**, but instead continue until it finishes the call. This recursion happens n times (where n is the list's length), and you will see this behavior exactly n times before the function finally returns the subsets.

I hope i understood correctly the question and managed to answer it :)